# How to "grep -a" without the resulting trailing lines?

Tags: bash

I'm using `zgrep` to search strings in tarball files. If I go the regular way I get:

**zgrep inside aaa.tar.gz**

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

so I'm using the `-a` option (Process a binary file as if it were text) and it does read the file, but appends two/three annoying lines before the result!

**zgrep -a inside aaa.tar.gz**

```
aaa.txt        0000777 0000000 0000000 00000000017 13507572577 011066  0 ustar   root     
root
insideinsidebbb
```

how can I remove it in an efficient way?

Comment: it does read it but outputs garbage as well, since it's a compressed file. Maybe a different approach and another output, but try with hexdump: `hexdump -C file | grep inside`. This will not output the garbage, but a hexadamical line with the match, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The garbage you get is the TAR headers, because your tarball is a file encapsulated in a TAR archive, and then compressed with GZIP.

The best way to grep your tarball is :

```
tar -xzOf aaa.tar.gz | grep inside
```

- `x` : extract
- `z` : archive is compressed with GZIP
- `O` : output to stdout (assuming GNU `tar` or libarchive `bsdtar`)
- `f` : the archive to extract

You don't need the "-a" option of grep, because tar's output is already plain text (assuming it contains only text files).

Comment: If the files _within the `tar` archive_ are non-ASCII files, then `-a` may still be needed.

Comment: As I see in his example, there's a single `aaa.txt` in his archive. If there are other files, he can select what file to extract with the tar command, or even use a wildcard to select all `.txt` files  : `tar -xzOf aaa.tar.gz --wildcards "*.txt"`

Comment: Thank you guys :))))) It seems to be working: `tar -xzOf bin.tar.gz | grep -a insideTextIWant`

Comment: @N-Mi with both gnu tar and bsdtar you can omit the `z`; that will let the command work with any tar archive, no matter if compressed with `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, etc. `bsdtar` will even do .zips and .isos.

Comment: @mosvy you're right :) putting `z` is more an old habit than a real need, even if I know it works without it.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `tar`, you can use the `--to-command` option to pipe each archive member to `grep`, so (with GNU `grep` and its `--label` option) you can also get the name of the embedded files that contain the match:

```
$ tar --to-command='grep -aH --label="$TAR_ARCHIVE[$TAR_FILENAME]" inside || true' -xf awk.tar.gz
awk.tar.gz[ytab.c]:                             SYNTAX("next is illegal inside a function");
awk.tar.gz[ytab.c]:                             SYNTAX("nextfile is illegal inside a function");
awk.tar.gz[awkgram.y]:                          SYNTAX("next is illegal inside a function");
awk.tar.gz[awkgram.y]:                          SYNTAX("nextfile is illegal inside a function");
awk.tar.gz[lex.c]:/* BUG: this ought to be inside the if; in theory could fault (daniel barrett) */
awk.tar.gz[ytabc.bak]:                          SYNTAX("next is illegal inside a function");
awk.tar.gz[ytabc.bak]:                          SYNTAX("nextfile is illegal inside a function");
```

The `|| true` is to avoid the `tar: 2631: Child returned status 1` warnings when `grep` doesn't find any occurrence in an archive member.

You can write a `targrep` helper function or script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
export PATTERN="${1?}"
shift
for file do
  tar --to-command='
    grep -aPH --label="$TAR_ARCHIVE[$TAR_FILENAME]" -e "$PATTERN" || true
  ' -xf "$file"
done
```

To be used as:

```
targrep inside *.tar.*
```

Here using PCRE, which are the most feature-full regexps supported by GNU `tar`, so you can do case insensitive matching for instance with:

```
targrep '(?i)inside' *.tar.*
```

(avoiding having to do more complex option parsing in the script to support a `-i` option).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert the NUL characters (which often delimit strings in binary files) to newlines, before grepping which would work for `tar` files like in your case but potentially other forms of binary files:

```
file=xxx.tar.gz

zcat -f < "$file" | tr '\0' '\n' | grep -a inside
```